# Using Websocketsharp.SetProxy in C#

Tags: c#

I want to connect `websocketsharp` with proxy with IP and port format `27.73.116.44:20192`. However, the library only supports `public void SetProxy (string url, string username, string password)`.

My code:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket ($ "ws: //echo.websocket.org"))
{
    ws.OnMessage + = (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine (e.Data);
    };
    ws.SetProxy ("", "", "");
    ws.Connect ();
    Console.ReadKey ();
}
```

Comment: Which question do you have?

Comment: I want to connect to websocket.Setproxy, with the format 27.73.116.44:20192,
but websocketsharp only supports public void SetProxy (string url, string username, string password);

Comment: Do you use standard .NET class? Which version of .NET do you use?